# Using English macros in French version Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba, macros, input-languages

I am currently in France and am using a computer on which all Office programs are in French.

I need to use a Macro which has been written in English VBA, but it fails.

I assume the issue a language issue as the same thing occurs when I try using English Excel formulas in the French version (e.g. =sum is =somme)

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: can't you edit the excel macro and (looking at your example) replace =somme with =sum

Comment: I wonder if changing the locale on the machine helps?

Comment: What is failing? VBA should work as it's only written in English (previously, not sure about 2013). What error are you getting? It may be a regional setting that you need to modify. Worksheet functions should translate automatically, everything else should work fine.

Comment: If the macro adds items to the menus etc. it can run into trouble because these ARE different from one language version of Office to another.  There are ways of addressing menus by ID rather than by name in order to get around this problem.

Comment: Can you include the text of the macro, as that would allow folks to suggest modifications that would make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options that involve rewriting your VBA code.

- **First option**: whenever accessing the `Range.Formula` property, **replace it** for the [`Range.FormulaLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property. The localized version of the formulas will be translated by Excel into the English version it uses internally. This will of course make your macros only work in the French locale/language.
- **Second option**: manually translate every formula hardcoded in your VBA into English. This will make your macros work in any Excel locales/languages.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a Excel Macro tool written in the USA and I wanted to use it with in Germany. The tool seemed to get locked in a loop after starting so it didn't come to an end.

I could finally solve this issue with changing the windows default for date, time, and number format, into US-standard like described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-default-country-region-date-time-number-or-measurements-format-HP010174131.aspx#BM2) . 
So probably the VBA code of the tool works with some data in US standard formats and it won’t work in foreign format systems.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Could you please add the steps you took to solve this problem? The actual answer is on the website you linked, but links can become broken or outdated, making this answer useless.